# iphone - mutableArray cannot store nil objects

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a mutable array that is retained and storing several objects. At some point, one object may become nil. When this happens the app will crash, because arrays cannot have nil objects. Imagine something like

[object1, object2, object3, nil];

then, object2 = nil

[object1, nil, object3, nil];

that is not possible because nil is the end of array marker. So, how can I solve that? thanks for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `[NSNull null]` if you have to store an empty placeholder object.

For example:

```
NSArray * myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:obj1, [NSNull null], obj3, nil];
```

`myArray` will contain 3 objects.  When you retrieve the object, you can do a simple pointer equality test to see if it's the Null singleton:

```
id object = [myArray objectAtIndex:anIndex];
if (object == [NSNull null]) {
  //it's the null object
} else {
  //it's a normal object
}
```

**EDIT** (responding to a comment)

@Mike I think you're getting confused with what's actually going on.

If you have:

```
id obj = ...;
```

Then `obj` contains an *address*.  It does not contain an object.  As such, if you do `NSLog(@"%p", obj)`, it'll print something like `0x1234567890`.  When you put `obj` into the array, it's not copying the object, it's copying the *address* of the object.  So the array actually contains `0x1234567890`.  Therefore, when you later do:  `obj = nil;`, you're only affecting the pointer *outside* of the array.  The array will still contain `0x1234567890`.

Comment: Thanks, but the point is this. I am not storing a nil. When the array was created the object was not nil, but after that, it became nil. So, reading the array will result in a crash. So, what do you mean? can you elaborate?

Comment: In that case you have a bug. The objects in the array are retained by the array. In the normal case, the crash you mentioned should never happen because the object won't be deallocated until the array releases the object. In your case, somewhere in your code there's either a missing retain or you're releasing at least once more than needed. That's causing the objects in the mutable array to be deallocated while the array is still referencing the object.

Comment: I think you is probably right... then tell me please: Imagine I have 2 views created and initialized, viewA, viewB. What kind of array will I have if I do one of the following: [viewA, viewB, nil] ::::: [(id)[viewA, (id)viewB, nil]? I think I will have the objects themselves and the references to the objects, respectively, right? or will I have references in both cases?

Comment: @Mike references in both cases.  All objects live independently on the heap, regardless of where they're referenced.